# selenium python find element by id, add dinamic ID as variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pass an id of a web elemnt in a find_element statement, but it gives me error, I tried everything, I thing I'm doing something wrong, what I'm trying to do is something like that:

```
ref = '5555555'
driver.find_element_by_id("%s", ref).click()
```

Comment: Hi, should be `find_element_by_id(ref)`

Comment: your ref now is a string type. For ints, you should do `ref = 5; driver.find_element_by_id(str(ref))`